# I cannot use fonts in a folder to my asp.net web application (not asp.net website)

Tags: css, asp.net, fonts

I used to utilize custom fonts in my previous project. I used to, for example, put the font files DroidNaskh-Bold.eot, DroidNaskh-Bold.woff, DroidNaskh-Bold.woff2, and DroidNaskh-Bold.ttf. Then I used the following CSS code in my stylesheet file:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family:"Droid Arabic Naskh";
    font-style:normal;
    src:(DroidNaskh-Bold.eot) format('embedded-opentype');
    src:url(Fonts/DroidNaskh-Bold.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
    url(Fonts/DroidNaskh-Bold.woff2) format('woff2'),
    url(Fonts/DroidNaskh-Bold.woff) format('woff'),
    url(Fonts/DroidNaskh-Bold.ttf) format('truetype');   
}
```

which worked. Now I am working on an asp.net web application, where I created a *Fonts* folder where I placed the fonts. I am using the very code above, but it does not work. Is there anything I don't know on how to do it in web application?

Comment: Have you verified that the proper mime types are setup in IIS?

Comment: The relative pathing is kind of suspicious. You're referencing "Fonts/[FontName]". Should it be that or should it be "/Fonts/[FontName]" obviously with the slash in front being  the difference.

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick I am not using IIS. I am using Development Server

Comment: Thank you @KeyvanSadralodabai. In asp.net website that kind of relative path worked but in asp.net application, it only worked when I added a forward slash in front of the path as you have mentioned.

Comment: I still have problems with this. Although using /Fonts/[fontname] path works locally, it doesn't work once uploaded to host.

Comment: What does the full (URL) path to the font look like in your host that you uploaded to?

Comment: @KeyvanSadralodabai I just found that my fonts folder was not uploaded by Visual Studio Publish probably because the web application project apparently does not consider this folder to be part of itself, compared with Web Site mode. Why? I don't know. I just uploaded the folder (fonts) with FileZilla and fonts were applied.

Comment: If you have a solution, then you can right-click on the fonts folder and click on "Include in project" and that should include the fonts folder in any publish setting.

Comment: I have got solution. but, only "Exclude from project" is available in it once clicked.

Comment: I used a workaround by adding fonts folder later on via ftp after publishing the project.